# Using Dynamic LINQ Where in a one-to-many Entity Framework relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ienumerable, one-to-many, dynamic-linq

I am using EF 6 and .net 4.5. 
I have a "Documents" table with the PK "DocumentId" (Int) and another column, "Title". I have another table called "DocumentFilters" with the columns "DocumentId" (Int) and "DocGUID" (Guid). There is a FK on "Doc Id" between the two tables. It is a one to many Id's relationship between the Documents and DocumentFilters tables. The Model looks like this:

[image: DocModel]

I'm trying to write a Dynamic LINQ query using the DynamicLibrary.cs library from the NuGet package.

With regular Linq, the query looks something like this in c#:

```
DocDBContext db = new DocDBContext();
var documents = db.Documents.Include(d => d.DocumentFilters);
Guid gTest = Guid.Parse("xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx");

documents = documents.Where(d => d.DocumentFilters.Select(f => f.DocGUID).Contains(gTest));
```

This works perfectly and retrieves the documents delimited by the GUID filter that I'm interested in. However, I need to place this within a filter string dynamically, where it may contain other filters. Is it possible to do that? I've tried code like:

```
documents = documents.Where("DocumentFilters.Select(DocGUID).Contains(@0)", gTest);
```

Error: No applicable aggregate method 'Select' exists

or

```
documents = documents.Where("DocumentFilters.DocGUID=@0", gTest);
```

Error: GUID property does not exist on DocumentFilters.
(Which makes sense because DocumentFilters is a collection).

I also thought it might be worth to give this a shot:

```
documents = documents.Where("DocumentFilters.AsQueryable().Select(DocGUID).Contains(@0)", gTest);
```

But again, it doesn't look like the library supports AsQueryable and throws
Error: No applicable aggregate method 'AsQueryable' exists.

Is it possible to write such a restriction on a property of an enumerable object within the Documents table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So one solution was to modify Dynamic.cs by adding "*Select*" to the `IEnumerableSignatures` interface in the `ExpressionParser` class. And additionally add it to the `ParseAggregate()` method:

```
if (signature.Name == "Min" || signature.Name == "Max")
        {
            typeArgs = new Type[] { elementType, args[0].Type };
        }
        else if (signature.Name == "Select")
        {
            typeArgs = new Type[] { elementType, Expression.Lambda(args[0], innerIt).Body.Type };
        }
```

However, after this I still needed to overload the `Contains()` method to work with GUIDs. I didn't bother to do that. Instead I realized I can simply use the already supported `.Any()` instead of `.Select()`!

```
documents = documents.Where("DocumentFilters.Any(DocGUID.Equals(@0))", gTest); //!!!
```

I also had to change the column name from "*GUID*" to "*DocGUID*" because when writing `GUID.Equals()` in the restriction string, the parser mistook it for the GUID type and not the column name, and threw the error that `Equals()` is not a valid extension for the type GUID.

Sorry for wasting everyone's time!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Dynamic Linq](https://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/), it can be used against strings.

Comment: I am trying to use it. Anyways I found the solution already. Thanks!